# select desired column from pivot table and show in view

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

These are my model i want to show some desired column in my view as you can see but the issue is that the desired column like employ name employ no is getting from employ table but course name is not showing or displaying in view table. Is there a way to show the course name in course column in view.

**This is my View**

```
<table border="1">
   <tr>
     <th>Full name</th>
     <th>Emp no</th>
     <th>salary</th>
     <th>course</th>
   </tr>
   @foreach($data as $item) 
     <tr>
       <th>{{$item['Full_name']}} </th>
       <th>{{$item['emp_no']}}</th>
       <th>{{$item['salary']}}</th>
       <th>
        @foreach ($data->courses as $course)
                  {{$course->course_name}}
              @endforeach 
       <th>
     </tr>
    @endforeach
 </table>
```

**This is my `employ` model class:**

class employ extends Model

```
{
    use HasFactory;
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $guarded = [];

    public function courses() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(course::class, 'employ_course');
    }

}
```

**This is my `course` model class:**

```
class course extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $guarded = [];

    public function employs() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(employ::class, 'employ_course');
    }
}
```

**And this is my `employ_course(pivot table)` model class:**

class employcourse extends Model

```
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $guarded = [];
}
```

**This is my `controller`:**

```
public function show()
    {
        $datas = employ::with([('course')
            => function ($query) {
            $query=course::select('course_name');
            }])
        ->select('Full_name', 'salary', 'emp_no')
      
        ->get();
        
        return view('teacher.teacher_data', ['datas' => $datas]); 
    }
```

Comment: Full_name  is the name of colomn in employs db

Comment: the main issue is that i cant show course name in my view blade

Answer (score 0):

in your nested @foreach in view $data should be $item to iterate over all courses from employee.

Then in your controller the $data could be like this:

```
$datas = employ::with('course')
    ->select('employ.Full_name', 'employ.salary', 'employ.emp_no', 'course.course_name')
    ->get();
```

Remember that class names must start with uppercase letters and database rows with lowercase.

Comment: Its giving some error (SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'employ.Full_name' in 'field list')

Comment: i use one loop for this after changing in controller  @foreach($datas as $item)

Comment: in select query, employ should be the name of DB table that employ model is using

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that goal with this:

```php
public function show()
    {
        // you need the employ "id" column to retrieve the related courses
        $datas = employ::with('courses:course_name')->get(['id', 'Full_name', 'salary', 'emp_no']);

        return view('teacher.teacher_data', ['datas' => $datas]); 
    }
```

And your view, I think should be as following:

```php
<table border="1">
   <tr>
     <th>Full name</th>
     <th>Emp no</th>
     <th>salary</th>
     <th>courses</th>
   </tr>
   @foreach($data as $item) 
     <tr>
       <td>{{$item['Full_name']}}</td>
       <td>{{$item['emp_no']}}</td>
       <td>{{$item['salary']}}</td>
       <td>
        @foreach ($data->courses as $course)
            {{$course->course_name}}
        @endforeach 
       </td>
     </tr>
    @endforeach
 </table>
```